# Admin panel works for short period, then links all go 404

Tags: administrator

I'm doing update and maintenance on a Joomla site that hasn't seen much care for the last year or so. When I log in as an administrator I can only click around for a few minutes before all the links start going to the 404 error page (though one time I got the 500 Error after clicking Manage Users).

Other clues I've been tracking include:

- Once the 404 problem starts up I can get back to the initial admin panel page (i.e. http://domain/administrator/) and CNTRL-F5 and not get a 404, but all the other pages are using query strings and remain inaccessible
- Turning off SEF URLS and URL Rewriting didn't make a difference
- After the 404 issue starts, the Maintenance section says "Unknown Joomla" and "Unknown Extensions"
- the problem existed when it was Joomla 3.4.0 and persists since it was updated to 3.5.1

New clues:

- It looks like the site dates back to the v2.x era
- The preceding seems significant because the front end is using Yootheme's Mustache template and it looks like that theme was not updated to work with Joomla v3.x

Comment: check the `$session` in your configuration if it is set to `database`. if something else is set let us know

Comment: have you tried downloading the site and testing it in a local environment?

Comment: @Ruchika, it's set to database, but should I be concerned the variable is $session_handler instead of just $session?

Comment: @johnny_s, I've only been thinking about doing that, though I was thinking more of starting with a new and up to date install, then adding or migrating live site stuff in.

Comment: @robe yes i meant `$session_handler` only :) correction!

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem.

Could be one of the following

• A component or extension is using too much of the cache and sending the system into overload

Try to identify this clear the cache and disable any extensions

• The menu items need rebuilding if you are getting 404

Go to menus on backend, select all and then click rebuild.

Hope this helps.